# Play Framework 2.0, Scala define input type and print a list

Tags: list, scala, playframework-2.0

I am using Play Framework 2.0,
I am trying to print out a table, and depending on the type of my data, my program will input different. I've already figured out how to define the class of my input using isInstanceOf, but when I do it on a List, it returns:

```
non-variable type argument models.Medication in type java.util.List[models.Medication] is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
```

Below is my code:

```
@(title: String)(content: Object)
<tr>
<td>@title</td>
@if(content.isInstanceOf[Date]) {    
    <td>@content.asInstanceOf[Date].format("yyyy-MM-dd")</td>    
} else{
    @if(content.isInstanceOf[List[Medication]]){
        <td>
        <table>
        @for(a <- content) {
            @a.name<br>
        }
        </table>
        <td>
    } else {
        <td>@content</td>
    }
}
```

Please help...

Comment: This is just a warning right? Does it prevent the code from compiling? The warning is telling you that at runtime the `Medication` is `List[Medication]` is erased and the JVM could possibly return `true` even if content was just a `List[Object]`.

Comment: It's running on Play, and stopped me from compiling... (or is there a way to turn off warning?)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the warning is preventing the compilation, it may be obscuring the real compilation error.

Try `content.isInstanceOf[java.util.List[_]]` in the *if* test (that should make the warning go away).

Also you need to *cast* content: `for (a <- content.asInstanceOf[java.util.List[Medication]])` in the for expression.

I am not sure how play template figures out it's java's `List` versus Scala's `List` so the fully qualified name may help.